# %config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina' how to convert correctly this line from .ipynb file to .py script file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ipython

I worked already with jupyter notebook but now I move to pycharm editor so I convert .ipynb file to .py script file.

**In my Jupyter notebook:**

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

**After converting to .py script file in pycharm it shows as**

```
get_ipython().run_line_magic('config', "InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'")
```

**I got the following error in pycharm for this line**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nusry\PycharmProjects\Parking\identify_parking_spots.py", line 28, in <module>
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('config', "InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'
```

Can anyone help write this correctly in Pycharm?

Comment: Try this out: https://varhowto.com/how-to-fix-pycharm-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get/

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you could write what things you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: @AayushSingla screen supports retina display, we can enhance the resolution of the figure by using this command